# Can a Demon collect a Soul Pact on supernatural entities?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Can a demon make a soul pact with Supernatural entities? My gut instinct says no, they can make pacts but not soul pact, but I haven't confirmed this. I'm primarily interested in Vampires but it doesn't seem unreasonable to try to cover all the splats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

p194 of Demon the Descent

> Supernatural beings can sign away their souls to demons, but
>   it doesn’t benefit the demon much. When the demon claims
>   the being’s soul, the demon suffers aggravated damage equal to
>   the supernatural being’s Supernatural Tolerance (Blood Potency,
>   Gnosis, etc.) as the being’s power is converted to Aether and burns
>   off. Even then, the demon only assumes the being’s identity…but
>   as a human being. If she claims a vampire’s soul, she takes that
>   vampire’s name and face, but is not undead, does not drink blood,
>   and does not necessarily know the intricacies of vampire society.

There are of course rules for mimicking powers...

queue "I want to be human again" pact.